# SSRS Native Mode - View RDLs in Explorer View

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In SSRS SharePoint Integrated Mode you have the ability to view all your reports in a document library by opening the document library in "Explorer View."

Wondering if there is a tool available which allows this same functionality in SSRS Native Mode.

I know that really SSRS has nothing to do with the Explorer View (that is pure SharePoint functionality) but from and end user/developer perspective it is much easier to navigate folders/reports in Explorer View, add files, rename, etc.

A quick Google search did not find anything...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the functionality you are looking for. In native mode you can view all deployed RDLs in the virtual directory of reporting server application. Go to reporting services configuration manager on your server then go to report manager url tab to find the url of the SSRS site.

Once you enter to the site you can browse through folders containing deployed RDLs and apply limited actions to manage it.